# Is 'day' a reserved word in delphi?

Tags: mysql, delphi

I have a sql query that selects the day from a date field - 'select day(field_name) from table_NAME' this query works when i execute it in mysql query browser but when I bring it to my system in delphi, an error comes saying that it could not find the field.
could 'day' be a reserved word for delphi?

Comment: No, it is not a keyword.

Comment: If it is not a reserved word, what could be creating the error

Comment: That's a different question. Please don't try to morph your original question into the question that you should have asked the first time, but did not spend enough time over to get it right. Please take this as a lesson in how to ask a question. Spend more time asking a really good question from the off. You asked if `day` is a reserved word, a simple question with a simple answer.

Comment: Now, if you want to ask the right question here's what you do. First of all state clearly your environment. Next of all provide the code that you have used, copied verbatim. No fake code please. Then explain what you expect to happen, and show what did happen. Explain how this failed to meet expectations. Make sure that all output, including and especially error messages, are transcribed exactly. For the love of god, don't ever say "an error comes ...." You get a precise error. Programming is a discipline based around precision. Don't waffle. Quote the error verbatim.

Comment: I'm sorry if this sounds harsh, but it's hard to be soft when one sees this over and over again. It gets wearing. Please don't take offence at my directness, but please do take heed of the advice.

Comment: Thanks a lot, will do next time and sorry i'm new to this

Comment: No offence taken, a really appreciate the advice.

Comment: If you're new to Delphi, then you should really take some time to learn the fundamentals of the Delphi language before diving into incorporating a database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `day` is not a reserved word in the Delphi language. The reserved words are listed in the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Fundamental_Syntactic_Elements#Reserved_Words).

Even if `day` was a reserved word, it would not explain your problem. That's because your use of `day` is inside a string literal, and you can write anything in a string literal.